# PHP. saving many pages as png from the command line

Tags: javascript, php, get, laravel-artisan

I access a page via GET (some of its contents are loaded using jquery), on document.ready  this page gets saved as a png.

I want to call this page from a command line  using inside the command a for loop to save multiple pngs. 
How can I do it?

If I run this on the browser it works fine but the idea is not to make it manually, one by one for each gln code.

curl did not work or am I using it wrong?

```
<script> 
@isset($saveCode)
            $("#btnPng").click();
@endisset

 $("#btnPng").click(function () {
        var selected_date = $('#selectReportDate').find(':selected').val() ;
        var selected_gln = $('#selectAccount').find(':selected').val() ;
        html2canvas($("#printable"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
                  var url = canvas.toDataURL();
                  $("<a>", {
                    href: url,
                    download: selected_date + selected_gln
                  })
                  .on("click", function() {$(this).remove()})
                  .appendTo("body")[0].click()
                }
        })
    });

</script>
```

command handle code

```
public function handle()
    {

        $date = WeeklyTopSheetsData::max('report_date');
        $accounts = REF_GA_GLN::Select('gln')->orderBy('account_name')->get();

        foreach ($accounts as $account) {

            $auxURL = 'http://localhost:8000/topsheet/' . $account['gln'] . '/' . $date . '/1';
            $ch = curl_init();

            echo $auxURL;
            //set URL and other appropriate options
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $auxURL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

            // grab URL and pass it to the browser
            curl_exec($ch);

            // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
            curl_close($ch);
        }
        echo ' FIN';
    }
}
```

Comment: a browser is required to render the page first if you want to execute the html/css code. Curl just pulls the raw page code which you will need. Now you need to render that code. Consider a 3rd party tool such as wkhtmltopdf. I think it converts to png too. It's command line so you will need to save the rendered page to a .html file then use an exec command to execute the command line tool.

Comment: Thank you @danielson317 !!   wkhtmltopdf did the job